# H1 tag not working

Tags: html, css

Below is a portion of my html code but the css for the h1 tag doesn't seem to be working. What seems to be the problem?

```
h1 {
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: #445668; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0 0 35px 0; 
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">
<form id="truth">

<h1> Truth </h1>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"  maxlength="30" /> <br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"  maxlength="30"/> <br>
Email: <input type="text" id="email" /> <br>
Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> <br>
Date to be performed:<input type="date" name="date"/><br>
Victim:  <input type="text" name="victim"  maxlength="30" />
<input type="submit" onclick="validateEmail();" />

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: working here http://jsfiddle.net/qpsogr7v/1/ i didnt see any problem.

Comment: you dont have opening <html> and <head> tags in the sample..

Comment: Just make sure you don't have a style or .css with !important before it http://jsfiddle.net/qpsogr7v/2/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the character encoding of your source code, not sure how you wrote it but copying into notepad and re-typing the line "color:#445668;" solves the problem. Guessing that you are editing linux code on a windows machine or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
      <html>
      <style>
      h1 {
       font-size: 20px; 
       color: red; 
       text-transform: uppercase;
       text-align: center; 
       margin: 0 0 35px 0; 
       text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
         }
       </style>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div id="box">
       <form id="truth">

       <h1> Truth </h1>
       First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"  maxlength="30" /> <br>
       Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"  maxlength="30"/> <br>
       Email: <input type="text" id="email" /> <br>
       Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
       Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> <br>
       Date to be performed:<input type="date" name="date"/><br>
       Victim:  <input type="text" name="victim"  maxlength="30" />
       <input type="submit" onclick="validateEmail();" />

       </form>
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  #box h1 { "your style "}  or  #box #truth h1{ "your style "}